# Installing the latest version of Spyder in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, spyder

I want to install latest version of Spyder on Ubuntu 18.04. I need to update Spyder to the latest version (spyder 3.3.2), because there are some errors with version 3.2.6 such as variable explorer doesn't show variables. I don't use Anaconda, and I don't want to install it with Anaconda.

When I tried to install it with `pip install -U spyder` I got the following error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/candan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/QtPy-1.6.0.dist-info/METADATA'
```

The full result is here:

```
    candan@candan-HP-ProBook-470-G2:~$ pip install -U spyder
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting spyder
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/ec/c8edcd40ff3af06cffa5bff1397ad63a3f5d34d36818f684d6e0f88fad44/spyder-3.3.2-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: qtpy>=1.5.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from spyder) (1.6.0)
No metadata found in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/candan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/QtPy-1.6.0.dist-info/METADATA'

candan@candan-HP-ProBook-470-G2:~$ pip --version
pip 19.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-19.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
candan@candan-HP-ProBook-470-G2:~$
```

I also tried to install it manually by downloading package Spyder 3.3.2, but it didn't work.

I can run the old version when I install it by using Ubuntu Software, but it is not the latest version. How can install the latest version of Sypder properly?

Edit:

For **Python 2.7** I'm using following command to update:

```
pip install --upgrade spyder
```

If the above command doesn't work add `--user` after install.

For **Python 3**:

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade spyder
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using an older version of pip, however version 19.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the `pip install --upgrade pip` command. The latest version of pip requires the latest stable version of Python (Python 2.7.15rc1) as a dependency. To upgrade pip run the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq spyder spyder3
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt install python2.7
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip pip3
```

Then `pip install -U --user spyder` will run successfully.

To install Spyder for Python 3.x run `pip3 install -U --user spyder`

Answer (score 1):

Note this message in the error output `DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.`

You should use pip3 to install spyder.